# I am getting the error message "File 'subfigure.sty' not found ". \usepackage

Tags: packages, subfloats, compilation-error

```
\documentclass[nemilov1]{Nemilov}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigrafica}
\usepackage[LGR,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ? When was it updated most recently? Is the `Nemilov` LaTeX document class available online?

Comment: The `subfigure` package should be present in any full TeX distribution; on the other hand it has been obsolete for about 20 years. Replace it with `subfig` or `subcaption` (check their documentation). By the way, loading `epigrafica` is useless if you later load `mathptmx`.